# getting error while trying to read athena table in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-sagemaker

I have the following code snippet in pyspark:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext, SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.dataframe

def validate_data():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
    spark = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    config = {
    "val_path" : "s3://forecasting/data/validation.csv"
    }

    data1_df = spark.read.table("db1.data_dest”)
    data2_df = spark.read.table("db2.data_source”)
    print(data1_df.count())
    print(data2_df.count())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    validate_data()
```

*Now this code works fine when run on jupyter notebook on sagemaker ( connecting to EMR )*

but when we are running as a python script on terminal, its throwing this error

**Error message**

```
AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'read'
```

We have to automate these notebooks, so we are trying to convert them to python scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `read` on a Spark Session, not on a Spark Context.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf)
```

Or you can convert the Spark context to a Spark session

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```